# Finding the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^kx^n}{(kn)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm reviewing some calculus concepts right now, and this series stumped me. I'm trying to figure out what its radius of convergence is, but it's not falling for any of my old tricks. Using the root-test, I want to compute: $$ L_1=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^k}{(kn)!}}\right| $$

where $k$ is some positive integer. Passing the limit through the absolute-value bars and $n$th root symbol, I now want to compute the simpler (?) $$ L_2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(n!)^k}{(kn)!}}$$

Which I can't seem to pin down. Numerical tests indicate it goes to 0, and that jives with an intuitive notion I have that there are always $k$ terms on the numerator, but $kn$ terms in the denominator. But since all of these terms themselves depend on $n$, proving that $L_2 = 0$ escapes me. Once we get this result (if it's correct), then clearly $L_1$ is also 0, and the radius of convergence of the series is $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks for any ideas you may have.

Comment: You can not pass the limit over $n$ through the $n$-th root, since that would change the bound variable to an unbound variable. See also the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$.

Comment: Why not the ratio test? It's just $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$...

Comment: @LutzL Or, equivalently but even more directly relevant, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1n}=1$ where the 'inner limit' $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I added the $n$th root symbol to the second limit so that my statements were valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use Stirlings formula
$$
n!=\sqrt{2\pi (n+\theta_n)}\;\left(\frac ne\right)^n
$$
where $\theta_n\in(0,1)$.

---

However, with factorials you are usually faster if you use the quotient test:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^k}{(kn+k)(kn+k-1)...(kn+1)}
=\frac{(1+\tfrac1n)^k}{k^k(1+\frac1n)(1+\frac{k-1}{kn})...(1+\frac1{kn})}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, I answered my question with your second hint. I hadn't realized that the quotient-test is just as good as the root-test in finding the radius of convergence, but now I see that both are good as they knock the exponent on $x$ down to 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{\overbrace{(n!) \dots (n!) (n!)}^{\text{$k$ times}}}
{[(kn)\dots((k-1)n+2)((k-1)n+1)] \dots [(2n)\dots(n+2)(n+1)] [(n)\dots(2)(1)]}
$$
and
$$
(mn)(mn - 1)\dots((m-1)n + 1) \ge n!
$$
for $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.